# error dialog box with Qt quick

Tags: qt, dialog, qml

i'm programming a Qt Quick application and I'm looking for a possibility to display the user errors. In Qt widgets there is QMessageBox but i can not find any equivalent to this in Qt Quick.

Sure i can create a MessageBox by myself but I can't imagine that there is no given possibility?

I found an ebook on the official site [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Developer-Guides#7f78a82c525d6a17d477021eaed1ead3) and there is an Dialog described on page 67 but it doesn't work anymore and i can't find any further information about that. Is it dropped in the current version?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Qt-Quick` component for this yet. What I do in my application is using the [Window](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qml-qtquick-window2-window.html) QML component. I set the `modality` property to `Qt.WindowModal` to have it as a modal Window. You can then use the [Button](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-button.html) component to create OK/Cancel buttons.

Another thing I do is create these modals dynamically when something wrong occurs using [Qt.createComponent()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) in QML.

**Edit**: Just discovered a new `Dialog` component that will be released in `Qt5.2` that seems to match what you are looking for: [MessageDialog](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html)